# NPM run watch err! Error [ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED]: Cannot call write after a stream was destroyed

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules

I am forget what i do previously. When i run my code some error's appear. I search solution to solve problems and try always way.

I cleared my cache but still error. I remove node_modules and install again but still error. I try like a post in some website but still error.

```
i use :
node v 10.15.3
npm v 6.4.1

error's code :
Error [ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED]: Cannot call write after a stream was destroyed
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:406:19)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:394:5)
    at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:294:11)
    at goToLineStart (D:\PHP\order\node_modules\webpack\lib\ProgressPlugin.js:90:27)
    at defaultHandler (D:\PHP\order\node_modules\webpack\lib\ProgressPlugin.js:74:4)
    at update (D:\PHP\order\node_modules\webpack\lib\ProgressPlugin.js:169:5)
    at moduleAdd (D:\PHP\order\node_modules\webpack\lib\ProgressPlugin.js:181:5)
    at SyncHook.eval [as call] (eval at create (D:\PHP\order\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonym
ous>:7:1)
    at Compilation.buildModule (D:\PHP\order\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:712:26)
    at factory.create (D:\PHP\order\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:960:14)
    at factory (D:\PHP\order\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:409:6)
    at hooks.afterResolve.callAsync (D:\PHP\order\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:155:13)
    at AsyncSeriesWaterfallHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (D:\PHP\order\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFacto
ry.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesWaterfallHook.lazyCompileHook (D:\PHP\order\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at resolver (D:\PHP\order\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:138:29)
    at process.nextTick (D:\PHP\order\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:346:9)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at onwriteError (_stream_writable.js:425:12)
    at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:456:5)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:406:11)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:394:5)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! order@1.0.0 development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-
modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the order@1.0.0 development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-24T08_11_44_990Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! order@1.0.0 watch: `npm run development -- --watch`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!`enter code here`
npm ERR! Failed at the order@1.0.0 watch script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-24T08_11_45_008Z-debug.log
```

if you want see log files :

[2019-07-24T08_11_45_008Z-debug.log]
0 info it worked if it ends with ok

1 verbose cli [ 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe',

1 verbose cli   'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',

1 verbose cli   'run',

1 verbose cli   'watch' ]

2 info using npm@6.4.1

3 info using node@v10.15.3

4 verbose run-script [ 'prewatch', 'watch', 'postwatch' ]

5 info lifecycle order@1.0.0~prewatch: order@1.0.0

6 info lifecycle order@1.0.0~watch: order@1.0.0

7 verbose lifecycle order@1.0.0~watch: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true

8 verbose lifecycle order@1.0.0~watch: PATH: C:\Program 
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-
bin;D:\PHP\order\node_modules.bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm

9 verbose lifecycle order@1.0.0~watch: CWD: D:\PHP\order

10 silly lifecycle order@1.0.0~watch: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'npm run development -- --watch' ]

11 silly lifecycle order@1.0.0~watch: Returned: code: 1  signal: null

12 info lifecycle order@1.0.0~watch: Failed to exec watch script

13 verbose stack Error: order@1.0.0 watch: `npm run development -- --watch`

13 verbose stack Exit status 1

13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter. (C:\Program 
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)

13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:189:13)

13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)

13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)

13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)

13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)

14 verbose pkgid order@1.0.0

15 verbose cwd D:\PHP\order

16 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601

17 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "run" "watch"

18 verbose node v10.15.3

19 verbose npm  v6.4.1

20 error code ELIFECYCLE

21 error errno 1

22 error order@1.0.0 watch: `npm run development -- --watch`

22 error Exit status 1

23 error Failed at the order@1.0.0 watch script.

23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Comment: So what's in `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-24T08_11_44_990Z-debug.log` and `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-24T08_11_45_008Z-debug.log` - but if I were to guess, somewhere in your *code* there is a `write` to `stream` after the `stream` is `destroyed`